# How to use for loop to create Int array in Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, for-loop, swift3

I know this is a very basic question,

But I try lot methods, and always show:

> "fatal error: Array index out of range"

I want to create a 0~100 int array

e.q. var integerArray = [0,1,2,3,.....,100]

and I trying

```
var integerArray = [Int]()
for i in 0 ... 100{
integerArray[i] = i
}
```

There are also appear : fatal error: Array index out of range

Thanks for help

Complete code:

```
class AlertViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var integerPickerView: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var decimalPickerView: UIPickerView!

var integerArray = [Int]()
var decimalArray = [Int]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    giveArrayNumber()
    integerPickerView.delegate = self
    decimalPickerView.delegate = self
    integerPickerView.dataSource = self
    decimalPickerView.dataSource = self
}

func giveArrayNumber(){
    for i in 0 ... 100{
        integerArray[i] = i
    }
}
```

Comment: Reading the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID107) helps: *"You can add a new item to the end of an array by calling the array’s append(_:) method:"* and *"You can’t use subscript syntax to append a new item to the end of an array."*

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your array is empty and you are subscripting to assign value thats why you are getting "Array index out of range" crash. If you want to go with `for loop` then.

```
var integerArray = [Int]()
for i in 0...100 {
    integerArray.append(i)
}
```

But instead of that you can create array simply like this no need to use `for loop`.

```
var integerArray = [Int](0...100)
```

Comment: @JimmyHo Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 4):

Solution 1:

```
var integerArray = Array(0...100)
```

Solution 2:

```
var integerArray = [Int](0...100)
```

Solution 3(worst):

```
var integerArray = (0...100).map{ $0 }
```

Comment: The accepted answer is good but I think this is much more useful in general :)

Answer (score 0):

Because your array is empty, so the "`integerArray[i]` (where `i` is 1 for example)" doesn't exist.

You have to write something like this :

```
 func giveArrayNumber() {
    for i in 0 ... 100{
       integerArray.append(i)
    }
 }
```